# independent stereo cameras

Tags: stereo, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
My robot has two cameras for eyes that are in fixed locations but can rotate (pitch & yaw) independently of one another.

I've gotten the stereo camera node to work and have run my calibration successfully while the eyes are in fixed positions.

Is there a package that can handle the changes in viewing angles while the eyes are moving?

Thanks for you time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36904/independent-stereo-cameras/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: I don't think so.

Long answer: This is a really hard problem. In a calibrated stereo system, lookup tables are generated that undistort and rectify pixels very fast. If you want to allow changing angles you would have to produce these maps for every possible angle. If you want to support a specific set of angles you could do a seperate calibration for each of these and switch between them when the cameras move. In that case your system would need a very precise repeatability.

You could also try to setup a self-calibrating system which needs either information about the environment or some movement of the cameras.

Anyways, I am not aware of any package in ROS that supports anything of the aforementioned.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3